# Swift/Objective c - rotate/spin CAShapeLayer on the spot

Tags: objective-c, swift, uianimation, cashapelayer

Im trying to animate/spin  a circle around it self. 
did is what i have tried,but it just rotating on the entire screen.. i dont need it to move, i just need to to spin on the spot.
            let circleLayer: CAShapeLayer!\outside the method

```
        vlet rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotate.fromValue = Float(0.0)
        rotate.toValue = Float(2.0 * M_PI)
        rotate.duration = 1.0
        rotate.cumulative = true
        rotate.repeatCount = 1
        rotate.removedOnCompletion = false
        rotate.fillMode = kCAFillModeForward
        circleLayer.addAnimation(rotate, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
```

any idea why it's moving and to spinning/rotating on the spot?

Comment: You are adding animation to the layer itself, so it rotates the entire layer. I think you were looking after strokeEnd property in CAShapeLayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, i'll just rotate the view itself with diffrent animation :

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.95, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,      animations: { () -> Void in
            self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.sumer)
        }, completion: nil)
```

enjoy